# Move functions that use `this` keyword from a component into a shared service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I have a large component that loads data from a selected record into a FormGroup using FormBuilder.

I am in the process of splitting up this component into reusable services and child components.

I have a function that is called from the view to add a new row to a FormArray. This function takes the name of the array and the value to add.

This is working properly within the component.

Question: How can this function be moved to a service (or other solution) to make it reusable across many different components? In other words, I want to be able to use the onAddRow function across many components without having to re-write the logic repeatedly. Since this function makes use of the `this` keyword to access the current context, I am unsure how to move this to a reusable service.

Here is the component code that I am trying to be able to move into a service. Note that I have many other functions similar to onAddRow that use the `this` keyword and I want to be able to move everything into a reusable service.

TS Component

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  /**
   * Add a new element to a form control array
   * @param {string} formCtrlArrayName name of the form control array
   * @param {string} valueToAdd element to add to the form control array
   */
  public onAddRow(formCtrlArrayName: string, valueToAdd: any) {
    this[formCtrlArrayName].push(this.fb.control(valueToAdd));
  }
```

HTML Component

```
  <button mat-button attr.aria-label="Add Assigned To" matTooltip="Add Assigned To"
    (click)="onAddRow('AssignedTo', '', '')">
    <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: you could push the array from your component into the reusable function, add whatever you need and return it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

untested - writing off the cuff here but something like this should work:

```
// this is some reusable code in a service etc
public addRow(formCtrlArray: any, valueToAdd: any): any { // accept any, return any
  let myArray = <Array<any>>formCtrlArray;
  myArray.push(valueToAdd);
  return myArray;
}
```

then just call that from your component passing in the correct parameters...

Comment: Thanks! How would I pass in the formCtrlArray parameter from the html template?

Comment: Also there is an error message appearing before the onAddRow is called. `myArray.push is not a function`

Comment: you would still need to jog through your component's class method.  As for your error in your second comment, like I said I didn't test that.  The logic there is to cast `formCtrlArray` as an array so all of the array's methods become exposed (`push()` being one of them).  There are other strategies for casting to arrays so you'll have to trial and error that out....

Answer (score 0):

The advice provided by BlairHolmes pointed me in the right direction. Also here is a related article. https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2

Here is the solution I have:

Service

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  /**
   * Add a new element to a form control array
   * @param {string} formGroup form group of the form control array
   * @param {string} formCtrlArrayName name of the form control array
   * @param {string} valueToAdd element to add to the form control array
   */
  public addRow(formGroup: any, formCtrlArrayName: string, valueToAdd: any) {
    let control = formGroup.controls[formCtrlArrayName];
    control.push(this.fb.control(valueToAdd));
  }
```

TS Component (a wrapper to call from the HTML component)

```
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  /**
   * Add a new element to a form control array
   * @param {string} formCtrlArrayName name of the form control array
   * @param {string} valueToAdd element to add to the form control array
   */
  public onAddRow(formCtrlArrayName: string, valueToAdd: any) {
    this.uiService.addRow(this.itemForm, formCtrlArrayName, valueToAdd);
  }
```

HTML Component (unchanged)

```
<button mat-button attr.aria-label="Add Assigned To" matTooltip="Add Assigned To"
  (click)="onAddRow('AssignedTo', '')">
  <mat-icon>add_circle</mat-icon>
</button>
```